# Increment is not working properly in C++

Tags: c++

Here is the simple code of `for` loop. Theoretically after `for` loop, the value of `i` should increase to 1 but the value is not increasing; `i` retains the value 0 after the loop also. Can you provide me the reason behind this?

```
Integer j = 0;
Integer i = 0;
for(; i < m_ParticleNum; ++i)
{       

    if(m_aOutputParticleID[i] < 0 )
    {
        m_aOutputParticleID[i]                  = i;
        m_aOutputParticlePosition[i]            = bucket[j].Position;
        m_aOutputParticleVelocity[i]            = bucket[j].Velocity;
        m_aOutputParticlePressure[i]            = bucket[j].Pressure;
        m_aOutputParticleDensity[i]             = bucket[j].Density;
        m_aOutputParticleTemperature[i]         = bucket[j].Temperature;
        m_aOutputParticleKineticViscosity[i]    = bucket[j].KineticViscosity;
        m_aOutputParticleSolidPhaseRate[i]      = bucket[j].SolidPhaseRate;
        m_aOutputParticleType[i]                = bucket[j].Type;
        j++;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `m_ParticleNum`? Are you sure the condition `i < m_ParticleNum` is true when you get to the `for` loop?

Comment: To be clear, what is `Integer` here?  Is this the G++ class or something else?

Comment: m_particle have some value and the program enters inside the loop but the value of doesn't increase.

Comment: Depends on what `Integer` is as well.  Is it a typedef of some sort of `int` or something else?

Comment: Integer is user defined variable it works like int

Comment: @SubashShrestha What is the value of `m_particleNum`?  And if `i` doesn't increase, you would have an infinite loop, but you never mentioned anything about the loop being infinite.

Comment: Its typedef int  Integer;

Comment: m_particleNum have value 255

Comment: @SubashShrestha - The only other explanation is that accessing those arrays may be corrupting `i`.  Why not comment out that entire loop body, to convince yourself and us that it isn't those arrays causing the error?

Comment: Why do you track two indices?  Are there any operator overloads defined for `Integer`?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't looking at the value of `j` by mistake? :p

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie ok i will try you suggestion, thank you

Comment: please learn how to use debugger

Comment: @IronSavior: Note that `i` is keeping track of where values get copied to, and change with every iteration (or should, anyway); `j` is tracking where the values come from, and only gets incremented when values get copied, which does not occur for every `i`, hence the need for 2 distinct variables.

Comment: It's the end of the day for me, so maybe my focus is just gone--but it seems to me that the only thing keeping `j` from incrementing is because `m_aOutputParticleID[i] >= 0` when you don't expect it.

Answer (score 1):

If the value of `m_ParticleNum` is 0, the loop does not execute and so, the value of `i` stays 0.

Comment: the value of m_particleNum is not 0

Comment: @SubashShrestha: then maybe you should show its declaration and initialization so we know that.

Comment: The declaration of Integer is typedef int  Integer;

Comment: @SubashShrestha: What purpose does that `typedef` serve?

Answer (score 0):

Is the value i used in any calculation or output after the loop?

If you are just inspecting i using the debugger, it may be optimised so it doesn't retain a value. There is no guarantee that the compiler has to retain values in unused variables.

Also, if there is any range checking going on which causes the loop to be exited with an exception, the increment of i **at the bottom of the loop** will be bypassed.

Finally, as i is a user-supplied class Integer, it is possible that some nasty person has defined its operators so the ++ operator is broken/disabled by design and is not incrementing the value.

We really need to see how you are evaluating i after the loop and the declaration of the type Integer to be able to provide a better diagnosis.